# Php form on another pc

Tags: php, html

I've created a basic html page which include a php&mysql form for sign up/log in. Basically I have a home page where there is a login button that takes you to a php page (register.php).

The HTML page and the sign-up/log-in php work fine when I access them from localhost of xampp (from what I've read I think this is ok). When I open the HTML page from the containing  folder and go to the php page, it doesn't work, it just shows the php script. I have to send the project to my teacher for review.

My question is: Will the php form work on the teacher pc? I think it won't, because the database was created on my pc.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: _"Will the php form work on the teacher pc?"_ - it should, as he propably calls the html via webserver (http://..) and not via filemanager (file://..). The teacher also should be smart enough to set up the one db table.

Comment: php is a server side language so it will run on a webserver configured to serve php (like xamp does). That's why you just see it as text if you open the page directly.

Comment: Sounds like a relative vs absolute issue to me. Post some code for us all to see and check. At the very least, the `<form ...>`

Comment: Maybe you should export your database and send it to him too

Comment: @Lelio  Faieta so the teacher will have to open the project using xampp?

Comment: so the teacher will need to open the project using a webserver capable of interpreting PHP. Xamp is just an example of a portable one

Comment: Ok, thanks. What about the database? If I simply export it to my project folder is enough or should I do anything else?

Comment: @Robert1428 for you it should be enough. The more advanced way is to make migrations, but as you looks like beginner, avoid it. You can make eg. some script "install.php" which will execute this sql generated from export with simple form where your teacher can fill host, user, password and port for db connection.